# Why Microsoft developed async functions instead of changing the regular ones

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

Is there a reason or benefit to use "sync functions" such ExecuteNonquery for example while we can use the async version (executenonqueryasync) + the "await" keyword in order to execute and wait for the response?

In other words, Is there a disadvantage for using "executenonqueryasync" function + await command instead of using the old "executenonquery" function in terms of performance or other aspect?

Comment: So that all existing millions of lines of code will not break?

Comment: you can't always use async. and it's not appropriate to use it everywhere. it should be used when needed.

Comment: Why can't i always use use the async function together with "await" keyword instead of the regular non-async function?

Comment: @Omtechguy what about if you are in `Main`.

Comment: @Selman22 could you please explain what is the disadvantage of using it all the time? it just release the thread in ASP.NET and the application will still need to wait because of the "await" keyword...

Comment: So what you're saying is that you think Microsoft should have made everyone update all their code for .NET 4.5, instead of the decision to leave existing code doing the same thing, and instead providing an async *alternative*. (Sometimes a synchronous approach really is the simplest solution.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - what i am saying is that Microsoft could just add a keyword like "DoNotWait" so we could be able to use it before calling the regular Sync function and the default behavior will be Async.

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying at all, but it still sounds like you think they should have broken *everyone's* code, forcing everyone to either use `await` or change which method they're calling. That's not a good idea. Backwards compatibility is really important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `await` a standard method - you can only `await` a `Task` (or anything with `GetAwaiter`), which means new methods had to be written to fit the new pattern.

As for not changing the old methods or just recommending a pattern of `await Task.Yield()` beefore every long method call, note that there are **Lots** of depricated pieces of code in the .NET framework ([each and every method overload taking `Evidence` in AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to handle older programs - like any good execution platform, .NET is very concerned about keeping legacy support around. If everyone using .NET had to worry about needing to recompile everything every couple months because MS changed something, they would not keep using .NET.

Another good reason not to change existing methods is simply that the pattern cannot be used all the time, every time. There are lots of places where threading needs to be tightly controlled (UI frameworks including WPF, AutoCAD plugins) to prevent exceptions from riddling the code - this is much easier to deal with by avoid `async`/`await`.

Comment: Well, you can only await something which provides an appropriate `GetAwaiter` method with a suitable return type. `await` is pattern-based.

Comment: Very true! I'll integrate this into my answer.

Comment: @Aravol , why should we use await with Async function instead of the regular function that Microsoft may change it to "release the thread" as the async does? That is the question...

Comment: @Omtechguy See the last paragraph - "releasing a thread" means it has to return or operate on a new thread, which is unacceptable in certain situations.

Comment: Thanks!!! now i got the point!

Comment: @Aravol, By the way, is it ok to say that by default for regular ASP.NET websites i should prefer ExecuteScalarAsync on ExecuteScalar?

Comment: @Omtechguy I have never used ASP.NET, try asking as a question (though it might be the sort of patterns question better suited to one of the other stack exchange boards).